# How to create a json string from a php array data

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm looking to convert an array with values to a [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php) format but reading the function json_encode i cannot find an option to get this result:

```
{
    "image1":{"filename":"image1.jpg","alt":"","caption":""},
    "image2":{"image2.jpg","alt":"","caption":""}
}
```

My array is:

```
$prod['images'] = 'image1.jpg,image2.jpg';

$images = explode(',', $prod['images']);

    foreach($images as $img){
      $get_path = pathinfo($img);
      $path = $get_path['basename'];

      $images_array[] = array(
                              $path => array('filename' => $img, 'alt' => '', 'caption' => '')

                             );
    }

    $final_images = json_encode($images_array);
```

and my question is how can i get converted to json like this:

```
{
    "image1":{"filename":"image1.jpg","alt":"","caption":""},
    "image2":{"image2.jpg","alt":"","caption":""}
}
```

Resolved with:

```
$images_array[$path] = array('filename' => $img, 'alt' => '', 'caption' => '');
```

Comment: Well, obviously you have to add the missing fields (and so create a multi-dimensional array)

Comment: You need to build an array that matches that structure... then `json_encode` it.  Loop over `$images` and build another array with the correct keys/values.

Comment: Also, I assume it should be `"filename":"image2.jpg"`?

Comment: You linked to the PHP man page in your question. That page tells you exactly how to do it.

Comment: Yes, it tell me exactly how to do, but, the issue is that i have declared image1.jpg and i need to extract the name without extension, the alt, caption i will inject it later, so that array i have for the moment and that result i need to get, this is for im asking here....

Comment: Use `pathinfo` on the images: `$image = pathinfo('image1.jpg'); $image['basename'];` gives you `image1` without the extension. http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Comment: i have edited my question, as you can see im getting the info from a comma separated and converting it to array, so later converting it to json_encode, and that's because im asking how to get the result first example showing... Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly building your `$images_array` inside your loop.  It should be:

```
$images_array[$path] = array('filename' => $img, 'alt' => '', 'caption' => '');
```

Note: Make sure to declare `$images_array = array();` outside of the loop.